# Spring Context cache clean with MockBean fails loadLibrary

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

I have a configuration class that loads a library using https://github.com/scijava/native-lib-loader (Which is great).

Unfortunately, when using `@MockBean` it forces a context cache refresh.
I don't know why, but I can't run `NativeLoader.loadLibrary("my-lib")` twice, as I get that `FileNotFoundException: The process cannot access the file because it being used by another process` in the second time.

How can I make the configuration to be run once during tests or make NativeLoader load my library twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hooking the `NativeLoader.loadLibrary("my-lib")` into life cycle hook of spring I used static context.

```java
static {
    try {
        NativeLoader.loadLibrary("my-lib")
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

The main thing is using [`ExceptionInInitializerError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) which is built for this kind of static context initializations.

So when using `@MockBean`, spring does run `@PostConstruct` in each test (As it should clean the application context from mocked components), but the loading of the library happens once.

Answer (score 0):

Try lazy loading, so that the library is loaded effectively only when it is really needed, i.e. just before you call some of its methods.

1) Depending on complexity of your logic defining bean as @Lazy can help.

2) If this is not your case, manual implementation of lazy loading can help. E.g. you can use proxy that will load library only when one of its methods is called for the first time.

3) Some rework of the logic of your application may be needed to postpone usage of the code that loads a library.